# How to stop Eclipse from indenting extra spaces in this specific scenario?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I am writing anonymous classes, I want my anonymous class to look like:

```
SaleTodayOnly sale = new SaleTodayOnly() // line 1
{                                        // line 2
    some implementation
}
```

But when I hit `enter` after line 1, Eclipse will automatically position my cursor at `|` on line 2:

```
SaleTodayOnly sale = new SaleTodayOnly() // line 1
        |                                // line 2
    some implementation
```

And when I backspace my way to the front and write `{`, Eclipse will reposition this `{` to:

```
SaleTodayOnly sale = new SaleTodayOnly() // line 1
        {                                // line 2
    some implementation
```

How can I set my own indentation preferences (for this specific scenario only)?

edit: I have my `anonymous class` set to `next line`. It's probably a `wrapping` issue.

edit2: I give up. I'll just use java conventions of `{` on the same line as the anonymous class declaration...

edit3: after hunting around the `Preference` window, toggling without much effect + seeing how *Format* produces the right output whereas the problem described still persists -- I'd agree that this is probably a bug and I will file a report when I have time.

Comment: So you have _Automatically insert at correct position_ for _Braces_ enabled, right? Is the indentation of `{` done automatically different from what you get after formatting the whole file?

Comment: Yes I have that enabled. I don't understand what you mean by 'after formatting the whole file'...

Comment: @howlger if you mean whether the problem is still there after toggling `Automatically insert...` then yes, it still does that weird indentation.

Comment: When a _Format_ (Ctrl+Shift+F) does not change the indention of the the automatic positioning of `{` (that you want to have differently), then you have not found yet the right settings in the formatter profile.

Comment: @howlger interestingly, when I _Format_, the `{` are set to exactly where I need them. However, it seems like the problem described above still persists. (Just thought I'd update you about it. I'm going to stop hunting for a fix unless someone provides an exact solution)

Comment: In that case, would formatting on save via Save Actions be an option (as workaround for the incorrect automatic positioning) for you?

Comment: that does seem helpful ... but unfortunately my main gripe is not getting the formatting I need _during_ the process of writing the code. (it's one of those /r/mildlyinfuriating things). TIL tho :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your preferences. (Window -> Preferences, probably; on mac it'll be under the leftmost menu option ('Eclipse')) - in the filter type 'formatter' to find the entry `Java > Code Style > Formatter`.

The behaviour you are witnessing is non-standard so you must already have a format defined; you picked this indent behavior, or somebody did who set this as default formatter.

edit this format. Alternatively, check if your project has a custom formatting rule in which case, this same answer applies, but instead go via your project's properties and update the formatting rules there.

The specific rule you are looking for is `Brace positions`, `Anonymous class declaration`. You have this set to `Next line indented`. Set it to something else. It sounds like you want `Next line` (not indented).

Comment: I have this on `next line`, it seems like it's the spacing issue. When I hit `enter`, the cursor is set to the indented position, not next line. When I try to `backspace` my way and put `{`, it repositions the `{` to the `indented` location.

(see edits for an example)

Comment: Then file a bug; the intended behaviour as shown in the formatter itself is clear, and the 'Next line' option should not indent. But make sure you reproduce this in a clean, nearly empty source file first.

Comment: If it's really a bug then I'll do that then. Here's to my first bug report.